# django-mptt count items in add_related_count?

Tags: django, django-mptt

How to add `filter(is_public=True)` to Question?

```
Category.objects.add_related_count(
  Category.objects.filter(is_public=True), 
  Question,
  'category',
  'question_counts',
  cumulative=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `extra_filters=…` parameter of the [**`.add_related_count(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.html#add-related-count-queryset-rel-cls-rel-field-count-attr-cumulative-false-extra-filters):

```
Category.objects.add_related_count(
    Category.objects.filter(is_public=True), 
    Question,
    'category',
    'question_counts',
    cumulative=True,
    extra_filters={'is_public': True}
)
```